# OG image appears in twitter from wordpress, but blank box appears in facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, twitter

I am the journalism teacher at my high school. I do my best to update the web page and modify the html code or fix other problems as they come up, but I'm stuck on how to fix our current problem.

The newspaper articles auto tweet from wordpress via a plug-in. They then feed onto facebook from twitter.

I finally got twitter to pull the correct og image on posts, but when it sends it over to facebook a blank square appears and the format of the post changes.

At one point in time, several years ago, it worked...I was able to fix it...then it broke again.

Our twitter account is: https://twitter.com/bhsnorseman 
and our facebook account is: https://www.facebook.com/BryanISDBryanHighNorseman/

When I use facebook debugger it initially always shows the blank box, then I click scrape and it shows the correct school seal, but it doesn't help on the front-end post.

You can look at the Trunk or Treat post for reference on both twitter and facebook.

Any help you could give would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for "When content is shared for the first time, the Facebook crawler will scrape and cache the metadata from the URL shared. The crawler has to see an image at least once before it can be rendered. This means that the first person who shares a piece of content won't see a rendered image:" In order to overcome this, you can try pre-caching: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/#precaching

Answer (score 0):

facebook generates the cache for all urls you share if you chnage the image after share it will not not chnage when you shere the page on facebook again. and and facebook some times not getting images from og:image.

if you want to overcome from this problem please add #somekeyword  (would be anything) and share it again. I think it will help you.

Comment: fragments usually get ignored by facebook